# 12345678910987654321 in one loop

Tags: algorithm

I sat an exam today and one of the question was to print the above sequence using only one loop in any language. I thought a bit but could not solve it. Please let me see how to solve it.
Thank you.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i, d = 1;
    for (i = 0; i += d; d = i == 10 ? -d : d) {
        printf("%d", i);
    }
    puts("");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What answer did you provide to the question?

Comment: `for (i=0; i<1; i++) puts"12345678910987654321";`

Comment: actually I I thought to write two variable in a loop on will i=1, and j=9. but I could not make it. My answer is wrong.

Comment: @chux . haha. if that was the case it would be so nice

Comment: `int i=0; do{printf("12345678910987654321");i++;}while(i=0);`

Comment: @chux puts missing paranthesis

Comment: Add an `if (i>10)` condition that will calculate `x = 20-i` else `x=i`.

Comment: @flatmouse thank you very much. It is working
for(i=1;i<20;i++)
        if(i>10) cout<<20-i<<" ";
    else cout<<i<<" ";

Answer (score 1):

The expression can change but this one came to my mind now.

```
    <?php 
    for($i=-9;$i<=9;$i++){  echo 10-abs($i);}
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for (( i = 10; i > 0; i-- )); do
  if [[ ${i} == 10 ]]; then
    string=${i}
  else
    string=${i}${string}${i}
  fi
done

echo ${string}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {

     int i,j;
    for(i=1,j=2;i<21;i++,j=j+2)
    {
     printf("%d",((i-1)-(i-1)/10*(j-22)));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

this will work just fine...go ahead try it!!
Happy to help